# I can't connect KAction to slot on KMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, connect, kde-plasma

I have a KMainWindow:

```
//file.h
class MainWindow: public KMainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
...
...
...

private slots:
    void removeClick();

//file.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
KMainWindow(parent) {}

void MainWindow::removeClick() 
    {
    std::cout << "Remove" << std::endl;
    }
```

I can compile it correctly, but when I execute the I get the message

```
Object::connect: No such slot KMainWindow::removeClick()
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the Q_OBJECT macro.

```
class MainWindow: public KMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // [snip]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved using KXmlGuiWindow instead of KMainWindow and the Q_OBJECT macro